# cap unicorn:start task not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, unicorn

The following cap commands are available now, but I am unable to start unicorn using `unicorn:start`.

```
cap -vT
cap bundle:install                    # Install the current Bundler environment.
cap deploy                            # Deploys your project.
cap deploy:assets:clean               # Run the asset clean rake task.
cap deploy:assets:clean_expired       # Clean up any assets that haven't been...
cap deploy:assets:precompile          # Run the asset precompilation rake task.
cap deploy:assets:rollback            # to shared/assets/manifest.yml, and fi...
cap deploy:assets:symlink             # [internal] This task will set up a sy...
cap deploy:assets:update_asset_mtimes # [internal] Updates the mtimes for ass...
cap deploy:check                      # Test deployment dependencies.
cap deploy:cleanup                    # Clean up old releases.
cap deploy:cold                       # Deploys and starts a `cold' application.
cap deploy:create_symlink             # Updates the symlink to the most recen...
cap deploy:finalize_update            # [internal] Touches up the released code.
cap deploy:migrate                    # Run the migrate rake task.
cap deploy:migrations                 # Deploy and run pending migrations.
cap deploy:pending                    # Displays the commits since your last ...
cap deploy:pending:diff               # Displays the `diff' since your last d...
cap deploy:restart                    # Blank task exists as a hook into whic...
cap deploy:rollback                   # Rolls back to a previous version and ...
cap deploy:rollback:cleanup           # [internal] Removes the most recently ...
cap deploy:rollback:code              # Rolls back to the previously deployed...
cap deploy:rollback:revision          # [internal] Points the current symlink...
cap deploy:setup                      # Prepares one or more servers for depl...
cap deploy:start                      # Blank task exists as a hook into whic...
cap deploy:stop                       # Blank task exists as a hook into whic...
cap deploy:symlink                    # Deprecated API.
cap deploy:update                     # Copies your project and updates the s...
cap deploy:update_code                # Copies your project to the remote ser...
cap deploy:upload                     # Copy files to the currently deployed ...
cap development                       # Set the target stage to `development'.
cap invoke                            # Invoke a single command on the remote...
cap multistage:ensure                 # [internal] Ensure that a stage has be...
cap multistage:prepare                # Stub out the staging config files.
cap production                        # Set the target stage to `production'.
cap rvm:create_gemset                 # Create gemset
cap rvm:install_gem                   # Install a gem, 'cap rvm:install_gem G...
cap rvm:install_ruby                  # Install RVM ruby to the server, creat...
cap rvm:install_rvm                   # Install RVM of the given choice to th...
cap rvm:uninstall_gem                 # Uninstall a gem, 'cap rvm:uninstall_g...
cap shell                             # Begin an interactive Capistrano session.
cap staging                           # Set the target stage to `staging'.

Extended help may be available for these tasks.
Type `cap -e taskname' to view it.
```

Following gems are available

```
gem list --local | grep cap
capistrano (2.14.1)
capistrano-ext (1.2.1)
capistrano-unicorn (0.1.6)
rvm-capistrano (1.2.7)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you haven't required it in your deploy.rb.

```
require 'capistrano-unicorn'
```

Comment: I don't have it in config/deploy.rb, but it is present in config/deploy/development.rb

Comment: that file only gets loaded if you specify the development stage, but why are you deploying to development. Either way, it needs to be required from deploy.rb or the Capfile.

Comment: btw, if this fixed your issue you should accept it so others know it worked for you.